# Anyone know commands for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, command-line, static-content-deploy

Does anyone know how the following commands would be translated to Magento 1?

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami .
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod 777 -R var/
sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

These are for Magento 2 but I need to recompile and redeploy on my magento 1.7 store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 1 doesn't have a static content deploy system, or a DI system.

If you are using the compiler for magento 1 (you may not be) you can recompile with

```
php shell/compiler.php --compile
```

You can see if your compiler is enabled with

```
php shell/compiler.php --state
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Not Compiled
Collected Files Count:    0
Compiled Scopes Count:    0
```

You can use the magerun tool to use the CLI for flushing caches and performing the database migrations if you like

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#download-and-install-phar-file

```
magerun cache:flush
magerun sys:setup:run
magerun index:reindex:all
```

Comment: I keep getting this: -bash: magerun: command not found

Comment: Did you read the link https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#download-and-install-phar-file ?